# Munin memory graph missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, munin

I just installed Munin on Ubuntu 12.04. I had used it previously on a different machine running 10.04 and it has a beautiful memory graph. For some reason it is not showing up on my new install. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: is memory graph the only one missing? maybe Ubuntu 12.04 changes some configuration.. also it will be helpful if you can post your Munin config file

Comment: Do you know where I would find that? Been googling for a while, nothing comes up.

Comment: Yeah, the memory graph is the only one missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. There's a huge list of plugins in /usr/share/munin/plugins. I just ran:

```
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/memory memory
sudo restart munin-node
```

Showed up right away.

Comment: Note that for the above command to work, you should cd /etc/munin/plugins first. E.g. http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/4/9/enabling-munin-node-plug-ins-on-ubuntu

Answer (score -5):

I'm not sure I've understand you, but are you talking about free memory or total memory?

free memory: `free -m` - shows the statistics in megabytes. -g for gigabytes, -k for kilobytes, nothing or -b for bytes.

Total memory: just look for `Details` on the dash.

Please explain again if I'm not reply as you want. :)